# Session Logic for User Verification in Rails Migration

Tags: beginner, php, ruby, ruby-on-rails

This is a logic to create sessions on RoR 7.1.2 based on the last version of the website which was in vanilla PHP, with the upgrade I have to deal with the users that were already signed up but not have a password_digest attribute on his database just a password hashed by PHP which RoR with the gem Bcrypt cant understand, so with this logic it can access no matter were old or new users.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = find_user_by(params[:user][:username])

    if @user&.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      success_login
    elsif php_authenticate?(params[:user][:password])
      success_login
    else
      display_error('Invalid user or password')
    end
  end
  
  private

  def find_user_by(username)
    user = User.find_by(username: username)
    return user if user

    user = User.find_by(email: username)
    return user if user

    nil
  end

  def php_authenticate?(password)
    @user&.password_php && php_auth(password)
  end

  def php_auth(password)
    php_file = 'app/controllers/helpers/auth_password.php'
    output = `php #{php_file} '#{password}' '#{@user&.password_php}'`

    output == 'true'
  end

  def display_error(error)
    flash[:error] = error
    redirect_to login_path
  end

  def success_login
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

auth_password.php:

```
$password = $argv[1];
$hased_password = $argv[2];

if (password_verify($password, $hased_password)) {
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly looks good and sensible, but it does raise some serious concerns.

## naming

Using a `php_` prefix is *accurate*, and perhaps a good name.
But consider using a `legacy_` or `v1_` prefix instead.
Then we'll be in good shape if PHP rears its undying head again
and muscles its way into the codebase in some different form.

## hash pattern

```
    if @user&.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
      success_login
    elsif php_authenticate?(params[:user][:password])
      success_login
```

We're doing `if A --> success elsif B --> success`,
which is more succinctly phrased as
`if A || B --> success`.

But this is security critical code, and we're expanding
the attack surface to be larger than necessary.
Can't we examine some prefix of the hash, or test a regex,
and dispatch on *that* to the appropriate authentication routine?

For example, if you look at a FreeBSD or Linux /etc/passwd
or /etc/shadow file, there may be half a dozen
back-compatible hashing schemes supported.
Does the OS attempt `if A or B or C or D or ...` ?
No, it dispatches based on the hash scheme version,
which was carefully encoded to support such dispatching.

## collapsed namespaces

```
  def find_user_by(username)
    user = User.find_by(username: username)
    return user if user

    user = User.find_by(email: username)
    return user if user
```

Usernames are drawn from one namespace; roughly they match /^\w+$/.
Email addresses drawn from another, and we *definitely* expect
they shall contain an `@` at-sign, e.g. /^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/.
(Yeah, yeah, I know, localpart can contain more valid characters,
and with IDN so can globalpart.)

I would prefer to only probe by email address
for inputs that are known to contain an `@` at-sign.

More generally, there's a regex that describes valid username spellings --
only probe the database upon a match.
And similarly for valid email spellings.

## shell escapes

This is the one that makes me, and
[little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327),
*very* nervous:

```
  def php_auth(password)
    ...
    output = `php #{php_file} '#{password}' '#{@user&.password_php}'`
```

There's two different interpreters involved: bash + php.
Each is powerful.
Each does their own interpretation of argument characters.
There is room to lose.

Now, if we just ask for `ls` output, there's no shell interpreter
involved, as ruby does fork / exec of an `ls` child.
But if the backtick command can contain e.g. a `|` pipe symbol,
then ruby definitely delegates to the shell,
which in turn delegates to spawned children.

You should have a regex that describes a valid `password` hash,
e.g. `/^[0-9a-f]+$/`.
Only pass that password argument to a child if it matches the regex,
that is, only if it could *possibly* be valid.

Php accepts a wide variety of command line options,
which can potentially do interesting things for an attacker.
I don't want to know about them.
I don't want to have to reason about the properties of the
attack surface the current proposed code opens up for an attacker.
Much better to be conservative in what you send down to the child process.

## specification

The OP question didn't really flesh out the input space
in ways that would let an implementer distinguish between
good and bad scenarios.

## automated tests

This submission contains no integration or unit tests that would
increase our confidence in the ability of target code to
reject carefully crafted attack inputs.

---

This code fails to accomplish its stated goals,
which is to securely verify client credentials in the presence of attacker clients.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks
on this codebase in its current form.

Comment: i appreciate the feedback, and already made most fix. But there is something that I really don't know how to deal with. It is the 'Shell escapes' part, I think it's good thing have strong password so I encourage the use of symbols when making the password, and using a regex, it could lead to an predictable password. Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: Maybe you can predict how bash + php will respond to interesting punctuation. Many many programmers have tried to predict how an RDBMS would respond to punctuation, and they were surprised when "DROP TABLE students;" happened. We can design a system that has a large or a small attack surface. Strings that arrive from the internet are called "attacker controlled strings". I encourage you to accept and pass along a conservative subset of such strings, which you have adequately tested and which avoid exercising corner cases of two different changing and complex interpreters.

Comment: I made a new post with the changes :D [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289194/rails-session-after-migrate-from-php-improved)